# what programming languages have a trie data structure library built-in to them?

Tags: programming-languages

I was wondering what programming languages have a trie data structure library built-in to them? I am not sure because i didnt find any. Please help if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

None of the most widely used programming languages have a built-in trie, as far as I know--none of Python, Java, or C++ have it.

Python does have a third-party library called [pygtrie](https://pypi.org/project/pygtrie/) that is installable with pip.